# Calling image is deprecated

Tags: macros, twig

I just noticed this in my logs (when visiting my homepage on [www.sk8whls.com](http://www.sk8whls.com)):

> Calling "image" on template "macros/html.twig" from template "teasers/wheels.twig" 
>       is deprecated since version 1.28 and won't be supported anymore in 2.0.

An image is called like this (in teasers/wheels.twig):

```
{{ html.image( image, 'thumbnail', fallback ) }}
```

My macro is as follows:

```
{% macro image(image, size, fallback, alt, title, class ) %}
    {% set image    = image %}
    {% set size     = size|default('') %}
    {% set fallback = fallback|default(0) %}

    {% if image and image.src %}
        <img src="{{ image.src(size) }}" alt="{% if alt %}{{ alt }}{% else %}{{ image.alt }}{% endif %}" title="{{ title }}" class="{{ class }}" />
    {% elseif fallback %}
        <img src="{{ fallback }}" alt="fallback" title="" />
    {% endif %}
{% endmacro %}
```

I'm not sure why it's deprecated and how I can keep it working when the support drops with v2.0.

Comment: How did you include this macro?

Comment: `{%- import 'macros/html.twig' as html -%}` on line 1 of base.twig

Answer (score 1):

As from the [deprecated feature](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/1.x/deprecated.html#macros) list :

> As of Twig 2.0, macros imported in a file are not available in child
>   templates anymore (via an include call for instance). You need to
>   import macros explicitly in each file where you are using them.

Meaning you should also write `{%- import 'macros/html.twig' as html -%}` inside `wheels.twig`

Comment: Thanks for the link. Hadn't seen that one yet. This will require me to revisit all templates since it's used in several.