# Symfony3.4 Deprecations: User Deprecated: Calling ... on template ..." from template .. is deprecated

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I got the following deprecated message in Symfony 3.4.
I investigated this error, but the solution was to include `{% import "..." as macros %}`.
However, I have already put it in and I don't know how to solve it.
Is there any solution?

Message

```
User Deprecated: Calling "articleSearch" on template "AppAhiSpAdminBundle::adminmacros.html.twig" from template
"AppAhiSpAdminBundle:Hq/Article:index.html.twig" is deprecated since version 1.28
and won't be supported anymore in 2.0.
```

index.html.twig

```
{% extends 'AppAhiSpAdminBundle::hq_layout.html.twig' %}
    <div class="search">
        {{ macros.articleSearch(searchForm) }}
    </div>
```

hq_layout.html.twig

```
{% extends '::base.html.twig' %}
{% import "AppAhiSpAdminBundle::adminmacros.html.twig" as macros %}
```

adminmacros.html.twig

```
{% macro articleSearch(searchForm) %}
{% endmacro %}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calling image is deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44987282/calling-image-is-deprecated)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import the macro in each separate template where you want to use the macro

[See documentation](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/macro.html#macros-scoping)

Comment: Thank you.
I had to put ```{%- import...``` in "index.html.twig" as well as the extend destination.